# Docker: Unable to pull image from remote private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a private registry running on `172.20.20.1`. From another machine, I can use the HTTP API to retrieve registry info, for instance:

```
curl http:172.20.20.1:5000/v2/_catalog
```

works fine.

But I can't pull image from that registry:

```
docker pull 172.20.20.1:5000/my_image
```

I get 504 error (timeout).

Supposedly, I'm running the registry in non-secure mode. To do that, I have added in `/etc/default/docker`:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=172.20.20.1:5000"
```

and restarted docker service: `sudo service docker restart`, in all machines that run docker. Do I need to do something more?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer running my private registry in secure tls mode.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v /path/to/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/key registry:2
```

Then, I add (in each other machine having to pull from that registry) the certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.
(with boot2docker, I add that directive in `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh` in order to have that persistent across sessions)

I can then push/pull from any machine to that registry without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

I have changed `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=172.20.20.1:5000"` by `DOCKER_OPTS="-D --tls=false ---insecure-registry 172.20.20.1:5000"` and restarted;

```
$ sudo restart docker
```

and everything works fine.